# Complex integral of an exponent divided by a linear ($\int \frac{e^u}{u-1}$)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here is the question I'm working on:

---

Evaluate the following integral:

$$ \oint_{|z+1|=1} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi z}{4}}{z^2-1}dz$$

---

I've tried along the following line. Substitute $sin(z) = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2i}$:

$$ \frac{1}{2i} \int \frac{e^{\pi z/4}-e^{-\pi z/4}}{z^2-1}dz$$

The contour is a circle of radius 1 around $-1$, so substitute $z=-1+e^{it}$, with $dz = ie^{it}dt$:

$$ \frac{1}{2i} \int_0^{2\pi} \cfrac{e^{\pi/4(e^{it}-1)}-e^{-\pi/4(e^{it}-1)}}{(e^{it}-1)^2-1}ie^{it}dt = \frac{1}{2} \int \cfrac{e^{\pi/4(e^{it}-1)}-e^{-\pi/4(e^{it}-1)}}{e^{it}-2}dt$$

A repeat of the same substitution $u = e^{it} - 1$ with $du = ie^{it}dt$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \cfrac{e^{\pi u/4}-e^{-\pi u/4}}{u-1}du$$

At this point I've run out of ideas. Any hint or pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Residue Theorem:

$$\oint\limits_{|z+1|=1}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi z}4}{z^2-1}dz=\frac12\left(\overbrace{\oint\limits_{|z+1|=1}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi z}4}{z-1}dz}^{=0}-\oint\limits_{|z+1|=1}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi z}4}{z+1}dz\right)=$$

$$=\left.-\frac{2\pi i}2\sin\frac{\pi z}4\right|_{z=-1}=\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot from this answer.  I've suggested an edit with extra details for each step.  I hope that will be of use to future visitors.

Comment: Should the integration in CIF not be wrt $\xi$?

Comment: Yes indeed, @Alyosha. Thanks, edited now.

Comment: BTW, it wasn't me who added that integral there under CIT and now that I see it it is incorrect, so I will delete it all altogether!

Comment: @Andomar, if you think something *must* be added to one of my posts I will thank you if you add **a comment** under my answer. Please don't you ever, never again add/delete from my posts without my permission: we're not using here CIT but the residue theorem, which are *not* the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The comment above was my attempt to ask for permission.  SE should also inform you of suggested edits.  On re-reading, I still believe your answer uses both CIT and the residue theorem.  Is not CIT used to equate the integral with divisor $z-1$ to zero?

Answer (score 5):

Let

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi z}{4}}{z-1}.$$

Then, by the Cauchy integral formula,

$$\int_{\lvert z+1\rvert = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z+1}\, dz = 2\pi i f(-1).$$